# Cocos2d-x zoom in zoom out in rendertexture

Tags: cocos2d-x-3.0

I are working on a coloring game for kids.I have used bucket fill and it working fine but the problem is coloring image contains some small areas which are impossible to fill by touching on it. I wanted to Implement zoom in and zoom out so that kids can zoom in to small area fill it and zoom out. I have tried scaling rendertexture but it scale around anchor point. Is there a way that I can scale around the touch location ?

Answer (score 1):

Scaling will always be done around the anchor point. You have to reposition your RenderTexture, after scaling, so your touch location remains centered.